# Confusion - “CV including a summary of teaching experience”

Tags: teaching, job-search, cv, academic-life, application-cover-letter

I am going to apply for a visiting lecturer position at a US university. The job posting is mentioning that applicants should send (email) CV including a summary of teaching experience, and a teaching statement. I have two questions.

1. I am confused about the part "CV including a summary of teaching experience". Does it mean the usual work experience part in the CV, or do I need to send a separate essay of "summary of teaching experience" along with CV?
2. The posting is not mentioning anything about a cover letter. Do I need to send a cover letter anyway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. From the wording, it sounds like the usual work experience section in the CV should be fine, but you should really contact them and ask.
2. Always include a cover letter.

Never hesitate to contact people who advertise jobs for more information. It can't hurt. If anything, it helps them remember who you are.

Comment: Thank you. The thing is whenever I contact them they do not respond. That's why I needed help here.

Answer (score 5):

Besides asking them about more clear instructions, I would suggest having two separate sections in your CV:

- Teaching Experience
- Work Experience

from that, it would be clear which positions are the teaching ones, and which are research/other.

For this type of applications, it might not hurt to expand the *Teaching Experience* section with slightly more details on the courses taught, like

- title
- graduate/undergradute
- approximate # students
- whether you developed the course content/course materials

Your teaching statement is a separate document.